# Error: garbage option en script

Tags: bash, shell, debian, shell-script

Escribo en un archivo las instrucciones

```
COMANDO="ps -A | grep -v grep | grep 'nginx' > /dev/null"
if $COMANDO
then
    service nginx start
fi
```

Y me resulta este error

> error: garbage option
>
> Usage:
>   ps [options]
>
> Try 'ps --help ' or 'ps --help '
>    for additional help text.
>   For more details see ps(1).

La intención es verificar si se está ejecutando nginx, y si no lo está, entonces iniciar el servicio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es básico, pero siempre ilustrativo.

Tu quieres correr un comando y asignar la salida del comando a esa variable.

Pero `COMANDO="ps -A | grep -v grep | grep 'nginx' > /dev/null"` lo que hace es crear la variable `COMANDO` y asignarle la cadena de texto `"ps -A | grep -v grep | grep 'nginx' > /dev/null"` mas no ejecutar ese comando y almacenar su salida.

Si quieres ejecutarlo, primero usa un *command substitution*, que se utiliza de la forma `$(instrucciones a ejecutar)`.

En conjunto, la instrucción quedaría así.

```
COMANDO="$(ps -A | grep -v grep | grep 'nginx' > /dev/null)"
```

Pero a pesar de que no salgan errores, no significa que vaya a correr bien o indicar lo esperado. Además, ese comando no tiene sentido, se te quedaría de tarea ver el por qué, buscando más sobre `grep` en `man 1 grep`.

Algo que funcionaría, sería de la forma.

```
if [[ ! $(pgrep -f nginx) ]]
then 
    service nginx start
fi
```

Donde utilizo el programa `pgrep` que busca el numero de proceso basado en su nombre o en sus atributos. Y en en esa condicional `[[ condición ]]` pregunto: "¿No está corriendo nginx?", y si da verdadero - es decir, no está corriendo - , entonces ya ejecutas el comando para levantar el servidor.

O acortando la expresión:

```
[[ ! $(pgrep -f nginx) ]]  && service nginx start
```

Los puntos importantes aquí son:

1. Command substitution: es decir `salida=$(comando1; comando2; ...)`
2. Built-in `[[`: que ejecuta una expresión condicional, es decir `[[ condicion1 condicion2 ... ]]`

Esto lo tomo del manual de bash, `man 1 bash`, de las secciones de **Compound Commands** y de **Command Substitution**, esta última en la sección de **EXPANSIONS**

Comment: Con base en la respuesta, creé este archivo /usr/local/bin/services.sh

#!/bin/sh

if [[ ! $(pgrep -f nginx) ]]
then
    service nginx start
fi


Una prueba desde la línea de comando

root@88393:~# sh /usr/local/bin/services.sh


da como resultado

/usr/local/bin/services.sh: 3: /usr/local/bin/services.sh: [[: not found

Tal parece lo que escribe Marco lo hace con mucho conocimiento sin embargo no me funciona... debo estar haciendo algo mal pero no se que es, les agradezco alguna aclaración. Saludos

Comment: Eso es material para otra pregunta, sin embargo, rápidamente te digo que me parece que es altamente probable que es porque lo corriste con el programa `sh` y no con `bash`. Corrélo con `bash` o mejor cambia el header de tu script a `#!/bin/bash` , dale permisos de ejecución con `chmod u+x tu_script` y ejecútalo con un `./ruta/a/tu_script`

Answer (score 0):

Agradezco la ayuda.. me dirigió hacia el comando grep y lo entendí mejor, al fin lo dejé así y funciona correctamente

```
#!/bin/sh

pgrep -x nginx > /dev/null && rnginx=0 || rnginx=1

if [ $rnginx -eq 1 ]
then
   service nginx start
fi
```

Gracias